# Post update to Buffer API error - "Please select at least one account to post from"

Tags: post, postman

I'm extending an app to include semi automatic posting to social media using the Buffer API. I'm having trouble posting the update to Buffer.

Using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to play around with the API, everything is authenticated successfully and I'm able to `GET` anything I need, however, I keep getting the error `"Please select at least one account to post from"` returned when trying to `POST` an update.

After adding the required params to postman, I have the following request URL, which fails:

`https://api.bufferapp.com/1/updates/create.json?pretty=true&access_token=1/XXXXXXXXXXXXX&profile_ids[]=XXXXXXXXXXXX&text=This is an update`

After reading [this](https://twitter.com/buffer/status/416584587767468032) twitter thread, I have also tried the following with no luck:

`https://api.bufferapp.com/1/updates/create.json?pretty=true&access_token=1/XXXXXXXXXXXXX&profile_ids%5B%5D=XXXXXXXXXXXX&text=This is an update`

The full error / response is:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Please select at least one account to post from.",
    "code": 1004
}
```

The related documentation is [here](https://buffer.com/developers/api/updates#updatescreate).

What am I overlooking? I have a sneaking suspicion that it's something simple I'm not seeing.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried putting the POST data in the body of the request, rather than the URL? e.g:

```
HTTP/POST https://api.bufferapp.com/1/updates/create.json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

pretty=true&access_token=1/XXXXXXXXXXXXX&profile_ids[]=XXXXXXXXXXXX&text=This is an update
```

Comment: Thanks For headers .. it was problem on my end

Comment: Just to expand on this, the Buffer API requires x-www-form-urlencoded. If you're using node, you can use a plain JS object for the request body and then encode it using the `querystring` module (`qs.encode(myPlainObject)`) to send as the body.

Comment: Could you plz suggest me how to put scheduled_at with this..... i tried  the below ,but schedule date is not added to the post, but content is getting added successfully. "scheduled_at =\"2018-04-05T17:40:01.-14400Z\"&access_token=1/xxxxxxxxxxxx&profile_ids[]=yyyyyy&text=This is an update16: "

Comment: @Raji Does it work without the surrounding quotes? `scheduled_at=2018-04-05T17:40:01.0Z&....` or without backslash: `scheduled_at="2018-04-05T17:40:01.0Z"&....`

Comment: @ChrisBlunt what if I want to POST as `Content-Type: application/json`